# Remove spaces between words of a certain length

Tags: regex, r, string

I have strings of the following variety:

```
A B C Company
XYZ Inc
S & K Co
```

I would like to remove the spaces in these strings that are *only* between words of 1 letter length. For example, in the first string I would like to remove the spaces between `A` `B` and `C` but not between `C` and Company. The result should be:

```
ABC Company
XYZ Inc
S&K Co
```

What is the proper regex expression to use in `gsub` for this?

Comment: did  you try something like that: `(?<=^\S|\s\S)\s+(?=\S(?:\s|$))`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, that works too, post this code as an answer (so it will be an R answer too) `gsub("(?<=^\\S|\\s\\S)\\s+(?=\\S(?:\\s|$))", "", str, perl = TRUE)`

Comment: Are the single characters always at the beginning of the string?

Comment: not necessarily though i think that will be the majority

Comment: @Alex did you want to match the space in ` F` and `F ` ? ie, a single letter with preceding space. Another example has a single letter followed by a space.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is one way you could do this seeing how `&` is mixed in and not a word character ...

```
x <- c('A B C Company', 'XYZ Inc', 'S & K Co', 'A B C D E F G Company')
gsub('(?<!\\S\\S)\\s+(?=\\S(?!\\S))', '', x, perl=TRUE)
# [1] "ABC Company"     "XYZ Inc"         "S&K Co"          "ABCDEFG Company"
```

Explanation:

First we assert that two *non-whitespace* characters do not precede back to back. Then we look for and match *whitespace* "one or more" times. Next we lookahead to assert that a *non-whitespace* character follows while asserting that the next character is not a *non-whitespace* character.

```
(?<!        # look behind to see if there is not:
  \S        #   non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
  \S        #   non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
)           # end of look-behind
\s+         # whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times)
(?=         # look ahead to see if there is:
  \S        #   non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
  (?!       #   look ahead to see if there is not:
    \S      #     non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
  )         #   end of look-ahead
)           # end of look-ahead
```

Comment: definitely mad regex skizillz : )  can i ask you to explain this please?

Comment: just to be clear, i can have things like `A B C D E F G Company`

Comment: @thelatemail, thanks for giving it a shot. that's preciesly why i asked for an explanation so that i could understand what it's doing

Comment: no rush, was just responding to @thelatemail. appreciate the answer

Comment: @Alex if you have cases where this does not work feel free to drop me a comment.

Comment: cool thank you, your explanation is very helpful especially for a first time regexer. as a side note: when you say assert via the `(?` operator, that means it checks to see if the condition is true but does not include it in the match right?

Comment: Yes correct, they are "zero-width" assertions that do not consume any characters on the string.

Answer (score 10):

Obligatory `strsplit` / `paste` answer.  This will also get those single characters that might be in the middle or at the end of the string.

```
x <- c('A B C Company', 'XYZ Inc', 'S & K Co', 
       'A B C D E F G Company', 'Company A B C', 'Co A B C mpany')

foo <- function(x) {
    x[nchar(x) == 1L] <- paste(x[nchar(x) == 1L], collapse = "")
    paste(unique(x), collapse = " ")
}

vapply(strsplit(x, " "), foo, character(1L))
# [1] "ABC Company"     "XYZ Inc"         "S&K Co"         
# [4] "ABCDEFG Company" "Company ABC"     "Co ABC mpany"
```

Comment: thank you, this is great. i chose the other one because i really wanted to do this in regex

Answer (score 7):

Coming late to the game but would this pattern work for you

```
(?<!\\S\\S)\\s+(?!\\S\\S)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/47)

Comment: If you want to add it to your answer, in R this would be `gsub("(?<!\\S\\S)\\s+(?!\\S\\S)", "", x, perl=TRUE)`

Comment: I see you took the simple route or I just overthought myself. Good way to play games with my head =)

Comment: @hwnd simple is better :-) thanks for editing my reply, don't know what `R` is.

Comment: **Your regex matches the first space in** ` F` . See http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/50

Comment: same as the accepted answer, picky picky :-) `(?<=\S)(?<!\S\S)\s+(?!\S\S)`

Answer (score 1):

Another option

```
(?![ ]+\\S\\S)[ ]+
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this also through PCRE verb `(*SKIP)(*F)`

```
> x <- c('A B C Company', 'XYZ Inc', 'S & K Co', 'A B C D E F G Company', ' H & K')
> gsub("\\s*\\S\\S+\\s*(*SKIP)(*F)|(?<=\\S)\\s+(?=\\S)", "", x, perl=TRUE)
[1] "ABC Company"     "XYZ Inc"         "S&K Co"          "ABCDEFG Company"
[5] " H&K"
```

**Explanation:**

- `\\s*\\S\\S+\\s*` Would match two or more non-space characters along with the preceding and following spaces.
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` Causes the match the to fail.
- `|` Now ready to choose the characters from the remaining string.
- `(?<=\\S)\\s+(?=\\S)` one or more spaces which are preceded by a non-space , followed by a non-space character are matched.
- Removing the spaces will give you the desired output.

**Note:** See the last element, this regex won't replace the preceding spaces at the first because the  spaces at the start isn't preceded by a  single non-space character.