# Avoiding "&" in regex

Tags: regex, r

I have a string like `H B O & Co`, and I would like to remove the spaces between `H`, `B`, and `O` making `HBO & Co`. In a previous question I asked ([Remove spaces between words of a certain length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26538292/remove-spaces-between-words-of-a-certain-length)), I was given a very helpful answer to remove spaces in strings like `A & B Co` to make `A&B Co`. I would like to retain strings like `A&B Co` but avoid having strings like `HBO& Co`. To do this I was going to simply run another regex over the strings to fix those cases:

```
gsub("(\\S\\S)\\&\\s", "$1 & ", "HBO& Co", perl=TRUE, ignore.case=TRUE)
```

This, however, does not seem to be the correct answer because it does not use `$1` as capture group 1. Any ideas?

Comment: Try `\1` instead of `$1`.

Comment: Also, `&` is not a meta character in any flavor of regular expressions I've ever encountered, so that doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: yeh, good call on the `\1` instead of `$1`. what's the rule about about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your backreference is incorrect. Some engines use the `\1` syntax, some use `$1`, some allow both. To insert capture groups into replacements in R, you must precede the group number with a backslash. Also `&` is not a character of special meaning so you can avoid escaping and I see no reason to use `ignore.case=TRUE` in your call either.

```
gsub('(\\S\\S)&\\s', '\\1 & ', 'HBO& Co', perl=TRUE)
# [1] "HBO & Co"
```

However, since I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26538419/2206004) the previous question you asked; I say that you could avoid running another regular expression to fix these spaces and do this in one call by adding on to the regular expression I provided.

```
x <- c('A B C Company', 'XYZ Inc', 'S & K Co', 'H B O & Co', 'A & B Co')
gsub('(?<!\\S\\S)\\s+(?!(&\\s+)?\\S\\S)', '', x, perl=TRUE)
# [1] "ABC Company" "XYZ Inc"     "S&K Co"      "HBO & Co"    "A&B Co"
```

Comment: can you explain why it's `\\1` instead of `$1`? when i try it on an online regex checker the `$1` is the right one

Answer (score 1):

```
gsub("(\\S\\S)\\&\\s", "\\1 & ", "HBO& Co", perl=TRUE, ignore.case=TRUE)
```