# Remove spaces between a word and a number

Tags: r, regex

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26538292/remove-spaces-between-words-of-a-certain-length).

How can we combine a word and a number separated by a space in a string.

For example

```
There is a cooling problem in the component tx 313
leakage found in irc 256, fixed by replacement
Roasted cable in cpt trx235
```

The result should be

```
There is a cooling problem in the component tx313
leakage found in irc256, fixed by replacement
Roasted cable in cat trx235
```

I'm new to regex, so can't figure out a way to do it

Thanks for the help

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow, it would be great if you could show us how you went so far and reformulate your question (in order not to have an answer like "yes" or "no").

Comment: How do you define a "word"? What characters can it consist of? Any non-whitespace symbols, or those matched with `\w` (letter/digit/`_`)? What about `word 123 456`, should it be turned into `word123456` or `word123 456`?

Comment: You could try: `gsub("(?<=[a-z])\ (?=\\d)","",text,perl = T)`

Comment: a word in this case is just a combination of alphabets and similarly, a number is a combination of digits and `word 123 456` should be turned into `word123 456`

Comment: Thanks @Haboryme ! It's perfect. Could you please explain how did you go about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
text=c("There is a cooling problem in the component tx 313","leakage found in irc 256, fixed by replacement",
       "Roasted cable in cpt trx235","word 123 456") 

gsub("(?<=[a-z]) (?=\\d)","",text,perl = T)
[1] "There is a cooling problem in the component tx313" "leakage found in irc256, fixed by replacement"    
[3] "Roasted cable in cpt trx235"                       "word123 456"
```

`(?<=[a-z])` positive lookbehind to check if there is a letter before what needs to be replaced.
 what we want to remove, a space.
`(?=\\d)` positive lookahead to check that the space is followed by a digit.

Comment: I believe `gsub` is in base R.

Comment: yes it is! but i thought `?<=` is something from `stringi`  ..my bad sorry!

Comment: @joel.wilson This is [PCRE](http://pcre.org/) which could be used in all base regex functions by specifying  `perl = TRUE`

Comment: nice explanation and answer @Haboryme +1

Comment: I found a case where it doesn't work, ex. `checked trx 250 after 20mins` the expected result is `checked trx250 after 20mins`. Thanks for the modification

Comment: You can try `gsub("(?<=[a-z]) ((?=\\d+\\Z)|(?=\\d+\\W))","",text,perl = T)` let me know if that fails again.

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `str_replace`

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(text, "(?<=[[:alpha:]]) (?=\\d+)", "")
#[1] "There is a cooling problem in the component tx313" "leakage found in irc256, fixed by replacement"     "Roasted cable in cpt trx235"                      
#[4] "word123 456"
```