# Remove the Space from [A-Za-z]+(\s[A-Za-z]+)

Tags: notepad++, space

I want to remove the space between the two words only. To find these words in the file `[A-Za-z]+(\s[A-Za-z]+)` this expression works perfectly. But now, I want to know with which regular expression should I replace this to remove the space.

eg. 
**Original:**
tables, two tables, chair

**What I want:**
tables, twotables, chair

Comment: is this programming related?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26538292/remove-spaces-between-words-of-a-certain-length

Comment: @user1506104 need this for normal use

Comment: @cyberrspiritt but that is working for that problem. I'm still unable to get the desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to go:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<=[a-z])\h+(?=[a-z])`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *UNcheck Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=[a-z])  : lookbehind, make sure we have a letter before
\h+         : 1 or more horizontal spaces (ie. space or tabulation)
(?=[a-z])   : lookahead, make sure we have a letter after
```

**Result for given example:**

```
tables, twotables, chair
```

---

**Edit:**

For unknown reason, it doesn't work when we use <kbd>Replace</kbd> instead of <kbd>Replace all</kbd>.

We have to use:

- Find what: `([a-z])\h+([a-z])`
- Replace with: `$1$2`

Comment: You expression finding the exact space that I want but when I leave the Replace with: empty, it just leave as it is without removing the space.

Comment: @RajjatGarg: Strange, it works fine for me (version 7.5.1). What is your version? Did you check Regular expression and click on "Replace all"?

Comment: I'm using 6.3.3

Comment: @RajjatGarg: See my edit, I've just done some tests and I suggest another solution.

Comment: Done. Thanks for helping. This is really a time saviour.

Comment: I have a number of files having the duplicate entries. I want to remove these entries. But I don't want to remove the entire duplicate entries but only half of them. For examples,

**Source**

I have a pen  
I have a pen  
I have a pen  
I have a pen  
I have a pen  
I have a pen  
 
**Output**

I have a pen  
I have a pen  
I have a pen  

As, you can see I need only half of the duplicate entries.